# Ubuntu Software Centre fails with package catalog error

Tags: 10.10, software-center

I am running ubuntu 10.10 and was trying to reinstall indicator weather when I got this error message in the ubuntu software centre. It is shown in the screenshot below,

[image]

I click repair, but the message keeps showing up. I closed the ubuntu software centre and tried again and get the same error message.

Here is the error message if it is not clear from the previous screenshot,
[image]

**EDIT 1:** On running  `sudo apt-get install aptitude` it said I already had aptitude installed. Then I ran `sudo apt-get reinstall indicator-weather`. The output was,

```
indicator-weather is not currently installed, so it will not be reinstalled.
indicator-weather is not currently installed, so it will not be reinstalled.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgio-cil{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 274kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue?
```

I continued with a yes, but the problem still persists.

**EDIT 2:** I tried running `sudo apt-get install indicator-weather` but get the following error message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-weather : Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Can you please run `sudo apt-get install aptitude`
and `sudo aptitude reinstall indicator-weather` and edit the question with output of the latter?

Comment: I first removed the indicator weather package before I tried installing it again through the ubuntu software centre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have broken packages on your system.  Open up a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and that should fix it.

sorry for not commenting on my first answer, but I don't have the privileges.

Comment: That works! Thanks...I was beginning to worry that I had somehow broken my software center.